# REST API call from Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, rest

I'm trying to make an API call from my Salesforce1 App. I've created a global action and now I would like that action to call my API. I'm not expecting copy-paste solution but it would be nice if someone pointed me in the right direction.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at this resource yet? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1api.meta/salesforce1api/quickstart_prereq.htm

Comment: Somehow I overlooked that. Thanks, I think this is what I need.

Comment: No problem, I put it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to  this resource:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1api.meta/salesforce1api/quickstart_prereq.htm